# How to get only one record for a given combination based on a column in the same table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I am new to Oracle DB.  I have a Oracle table (EMPLOYEE) as below. I want to get the records based on the Max Effective Date for an employee:

| Emp Id | Emp Name | Eff Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Duke | 01-JAN-2022 |
| 123 | Duke | **01-FEB-2023** |
| 123 | Duke | 01-DEC-2022 |
| 456 | Mike | 01-JAN-2022 |
| 456 | Mike | **01-DEC-2022** |
| 789 | Jake | 01-JAN-2023 |
| 789 | Jake | **01-MAR-2023** |

I am expecting Output as below:

| Emp Id | Emp Name | Eff Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Duke | 01-FEB-2023 |
| 456 | Mike | 01-DEC-2022 |
| 789 | Jake | 01-MAR-2023 |

Can someone guide how to write a SQL query to get one record per EmpId based on the Max Eff Date

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use one of analytic functions (such as `rank` which might be better than `row_number` in case of multiple rows with the same date, while other column values differ - probably not the case in this situation), sort them per employee by date in descending order and then extract rows that ranked as the highest.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with employee (id, name, eff_date) as
  2    (select 123, 'Duke', date '2022-01-01' from dual union all
  3     select 123, 'Duke', date '2023-02-01' from dual union all
  4     select 123, 'Duke', date '2022-12-01' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 456, 'Mike', date '2022-01-01' from dual union all
  7     select 456, 'Mike', date '2022-12-01' from dual
  8    ),
```

Query:

```
  9  temp as
 10    (select id, name, eff_date,
 11       rank() over (partition by id order by eff_date desc) rnk
 12     from employee
 13    )
 14  select id, name, eff_date from temp
 15  where rnk = 1;

        ID NAME EFF_DATE
---------- ---- -----------
       123 Duke 01-FEB-2023
       456 Mike 01-DEC-2022

SQL>
```

---

Option we used before analytic functions were introduced finds max date in a subquery, but that option is now *worse* than the previous one as it scans the same table (`employees`) twice.

```
<snip>
  9  select id, name, eff_date
 10  from employee a
 11  where a.eff_date = (select max(b.eff_date)
 12                      from employee b
 13                      where b.id = a.id
 14                     );

        ID NAME EFF_DATE
---------- ---- -----------
       123 Duke 01-FEB-2023
       456 Mike 01-DEC-2022

SQL>
```